# .htaccess redirect something to something.html

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect

How to derirect

```
http://www.mysite.com/something
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.com/something.html
```

And

```
http://www.mysite.com/#something
```

to

```
http://www.mysite.com/something.html
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first you can use,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^something((/)?)$ something.html [nc]
```

Or more generally if you want `http://mysite.com/X` to go to `X.html`,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)((/)?)$ $1.html [nc]
```

`http://www.mysite.com/#something` can't be redirected with a rewrite rule, everything after the `#` never gets passed to the server. You will need to use JavaScript to redirect those links.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)((/?))$ $1.html [nc] this is what i need, but somehow it doesnt work. Its Internal Server error 500...

Comment: @DominikLevytskyi Ah sorry, I forgot a `RewriteCond` before the rule, since `something.html` would match the rule and get redirected to `something.html.html`, etc. and would end up in an infinite loop. The `RewriteCond` will make sure not to rewrite any URLs that already have `.html` at the end.

Comment: thank you! Hmmm, but now it seems like now it redirects everything (paths to css, images) And i need only the page URLs to be redirected :(

Comment: @DominikLevytskyi Updated once more. Now it will only redirect if the URL doesn't have a "." in it, so "blah.css" will pass through to the right file. The other method is to add more RewriteCond's for the files you want to pass through.